# Next.js catch all route not working as expected with getStaticPaths

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Next.js catch all route not working with `getStaticPaths`. According to documentation, I want to navigate to `t/a.cat` and `t/a.cat/a.id`, but it only works for `t/a.cat/a.id`.

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/foods`).then((res) => {
        const data = res;
        const paths = data.map((a) => ({
            params: {
                t: [a.cat, a.id],
            },
        }));
        return {
            paths,
            fallback: false,
        };
    });
};
```

Comment: How are you making your paths?  If you're using the filesystem-basd way, you need to share your file structure.

Comment: Hello, my path structure is: pages/data/[...t].js

Answer (score 4):

That's because you're only returning `t: [a.cat, a.id]` in your paths. You'll need to return `t: [a.cat]` in the paths as well.

```js
const paths = data.map((a) => ([
    { params: { t: [a.cat] } }
    { params: { t: [a.cat, a.id] } }
])).flat();
```